# Solve giving an extraneous solution to an algebraic equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am using (Mathematica 10). Here is my code.

```
$Assumptions = ν > 0
(* ν > 0 *)

lhs = ν Sqrt[Pi]/4; 
rhs = (1/3 + 2/3 x^(-3/2) - x^(-1))^(1/2); 
eq = lhs == rhs
(* (Sqrt[π] ν)/4 == Sqrt[1/3 + 2/(3 x^(3/2)) - 1/x] *)

sols = Solve[eq, x] /. {ν -> 0.2}
(* {{x -> 4.08572 - 3.05311*10^-16 I}, {x -> 
   0.847608 - 2.10942*10^-15 I}, {x -> 1.21145 + 2.55351*10^-15 I}} *)

lhs /. {ν -> 0.2}
(* 0.0886227 *)

rhs /. {ν -> 0.2} /. sols[[1]]
(* 0.411465 - 1.12297*10^-17 I *)

rhs /. {ν -> 0.2} /. sols[[2]]
(* 0.0886227 + 1.42762*10^-15 I *)

rhs /. {ν -> 0.2} /. sols[[3]]
(* 0.0886227 + 8.97749*10^-16 I *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `Solve` is confused by the application of `Sqrt` to the terms on the right-hand side of your equation and introduces an extraneous root into its solution.

That root can be eliminated if we tell `Solve` to verify its solutions.

```
$Assumptions = ν > 0;
lhs = ν Sqrt[Pi]/4; 
rhs = (1/3 + 2/3 x^(-3/2) - x^(-1))^(1/2); 

sols = Solve[lhs == rhs /. ν -> 1/5, x, VerifySolutions -> True] // N // Chop
```

> `{{x -> 1.21145}, {x -> 0.847608}}`

That these are genuine roots of the equation is visually confirmed by the following plot.

```
With[{xmax = 1.5},
  Plot[Evaluate @ rhs, {x, 0, xmax},
    PlotRange -> {0, .15},
    PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, .2}, Automatic},
    GridLines -> {sols[[All, 1, 2]], None},
    Epilog ->
      ({Text[Style["lhs", 16], {xmax + .1, lhs}],
        Red, Line[{{0, #}, {xmax, #}} &[lhs]]} /. ν -> 1/5)]]
```

[image: plot]

The very existence of the option [`VerifySolutions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerifySolutions.html) tells us that `Solve` may find extraneous roots, so we should keep `VerifySolutions` in mind when we use `Solve`.

Answer (score 1):

The external $Assumptions = v > 0 is not evaluated by "Solve".  If you put the assumption into "Solve", you get the right answer.

```
sols = Solve[eq && v > 0, x]

(*   {{x -> ConditionalExpression[
Root[-1024 + 
   2304 #1 + (-1536 + 288 \[Pi] v^2) #1^2 + (256 - 96 \[Pi] v^2 + 
      9 \[Pi]^2 v^4) #1^3 &, 1], 
0 < v < 4/Sqrt[3 \[Pi]] || v > 4/Sqrt[3 \[Pi]]]}, {x -> 
ConditionalExpression[
Root[-1024 + 
   2304 #1 + (-1536 + 288 \[Pi] v^2) #1^2 + (256 - 96 \[Pi] v^2 + 
      9 \[Pi]^2 v^4) #1^3 &, 2], 0 < v < 4/Sqrt[3 \[Pi]]]}}    *)

x /. sols /. v -> .2 // N

(*   {0.847608, 1.21145}   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are parametrized and which ones are parasites depends on the value of the parmeter. This should make it clear.

```
lhs = 
 v Sqrt[Pi]/4; rhs = (1/3 + 2/3 x^(-3/2) - x^(-1))^(1/2); eq = 
 lhs == rhs;
sols = Solve[eq, x];
```

Now plug in values and observe the parasites change branches.

```
diff = lhs - rhs;
Chop[Table[diff /. sols, {v, .1, 2.3, .1}]]

(* Out[45]= {{-0.364739, 0, 0}, {-0.322842, 0, 0}, {-0.282579, 0, 
  0}, {-0.24399, 0, 0}, {-0.207135, 0, 0}, {-0.172095, 0, 
  0}, {-0.138987, 0, 0}, {-0.107967, 0, 0}, {-0.0792601, 0, 
  0}, {-0.0531967, 0, 0}, {-0.0303074, 0, 0}, {-0.011588, 0, 
  0}, {-0.0000649052, -2.89495*10^-6, 0}, {0, 
  0.00254356 - 0.0119178 I, 0.00254356 + 0.0119178 I}, {0, 
  0.00949133 - 0.0324441 I, 0.00949133 + 0.0324441 I}, {0, 
  0.019769 - 0.056968 I, 0.019769 + 0.056968 I}, {0, 
  0.0326799 - 0.0840305 I, 0.0326799 + 0.0840305 I}, {0, 
  0.0477417 - 0.112886 I, 0.0477417 + 0.112886 I}, {0, 
  0.0646038 - 0.14309 I, 0.0646038 + 0.14309 I}, {0, 
  0.0830015 - 0.174353 I, 0.0830015 + 0.174353 I}, {0, 
  0.102729 - 0.206474 I, 0.102729 + 0.206474 I}, {0, 
  0.123623 - 0.239309 I, 0.123623 + 0.239309 I}, {0, 
  0.14555 - 0.272747 I, 0.14555 + 0.272747 I}} *)
```